# Plot line in Kiviat’s graph hides the background text

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, plot, graphs

The following is the hexagonal Kiviat’s graph from tkz-kiviat package. Though the plot made is fair enough, but the lines of the plot hide the background text. I used stackengine and adjustbox packages as well, to align the text with the arrows to the place where its fair looking, but the two text boxes *"Dark"* and *"Well maintained"* won't move but with a little success. Ignoring the legends setup, i need the background text to appear clearly without lines cutting it through. The following is the code used:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathptmx}      
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-kiviat}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, arrows, fit,backgrounds,positioning,shapes,plotmarks,calc,decorations,angles,decorations.markings,intersections}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\tikzset{ultra thick,>=latex}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\def\trimspace#1{\trim@spaces@in{#1}}
\makeatother

\newarray\kivaxisitemlabels
\readarray{kivaxisitemlabels}{%
    &  \stackinset{c}{-0.75cm}{c}{-0.75cm}{Dark}{}  &\stackinset{c}{-2.25cm}{c}{-0.1cm}{\multirow{1}[3]{4.5cm}{\centering brownies/wheatish (fair looking)}}{}     &    whitish     &       &
    &\stackinset{c}{-1.45cm}{c}{-1.2cm}{strong}{}    &\stackinset{c}{-1.55cm}{c}{-0.9cm}{active}{}   & \stackinset{c}{-2.7cm}{c}{1cm}{weaklings}{} &       &
    &\stackinset{c}{0.9cm}{c}{0.5cm}{pessimistic}{}& \stackinset{c}{0.5cm}{c}{0.2cm}{\multirow{1}[3]{3cm}{\centering optimistic}}{}  & \stackinset{c}{0.4cm}{c}{0.5cm}{Realistic}{} & & 
    & \stackinset{c}{0.6cm}{c}{0.7cm}{\multirow{1}[1]{3cm}{\centering well motivated}}{}   & \stackinset{c}{0.5cm}{c}{0.9cm}{lethargic}{}  & demotivated &  &
    &\stackinset{c}{2.8cm}{c}{1.5cm}{Gigantic/Dwarfs}{}  &Normal & Average  &       &
    & \stackinset{c}{-0.8cm}{c}{0.2cm}{Handsome men }{}   &\stackinset{c}{-0.5cm}{c}{0.2cm}{Ugly boys}{} & \stackinset{c}{-0.5cm}{c}{0.2cm}{beautiful ladies}{}   &   &    }

\dataheight=5

\newcommand{\kivcurrentlabel}[2]{\checkkivaxisitemlabels(#1,#2)\trimspace\cachedata \cachedata}

\newcommand{\kivaxisnumbers}{6}
\newcommand{\kivcategorycounts}{{3,3,3,3,3,3}}
%\newcommand{\kivkumulativecategorycounts}{{0,2,5,9,13,17}}
%\newcommand{\kivcategorynames}{{1,2,10,20,30,100,200,300,400}}
\newcommand{\kivlcmcatcount}{3}

\newcommand{\kivlattice}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisangle}{360/\kivaxisnumbers}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
    {   \foreach \y in {1,...,\kivlcmcatcount}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisstep}{6/\kivlcmcatcount}
            \draw[help lines] (\kivaxisangle*\x:\y*\kivaxisstep) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x+\kivaxisangle:\y*\kivaxisstep);
        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
    {  \draw[ultra thick,-|] (0,0) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:1.0cm); 
        \draw[ultra thick,->|] (0,0) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:3.8cm);%-latex,line width=0.55mm
        \draw[ultra thick,->|] (0,0) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:6.8cm);
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxissteps}{\kivcategorycounts[\x-1]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisstep}{8.5/\kivcategorycounts[\x-1]}
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\kivaxissteps}
        {   %\pgfmathsetmacro{\kivhelper}{\kivkumulativecategorycounts[\x-1]}
            %\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\kivlabelname}{\kivcategorynames[\kivhelper+\y-1]}
            %\node[circle,fill=black,label=\x*\kivaxisangle+90:\kivlabelname,inner sep=1pt] at (\kivaxisangle*\x:\kivaxisstep*\y) {};
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\kivlabelnumber}{\y+1}            
            \node[label=\x*\kivaxisangle+60:\kivcurrentlabel{\x}{\kivlabelnumber}] at (\kivaxisangle*\x:\kivaxisstep*\y) {};
        }
    }
}


\newcommand{\LegendBox}[3][]{%
    \xdef\fitbox{}%
    \coordinate[#1] (LegendBox_anchor) at (#2) ;
    \foreach \col/\item [count=\hi from 0] in {#3} {
        \node[color = \col,draw,
        fill  = \col,
        shape=circle,
        inner sep=1.2ex,
        name=b\hi,
        ] at ([yshift=\hi*4 ex,xshift=3ex]LegendBox_anchor) {};
        \node[anchor=west,xshift=1ex] at (b\hi.east) (c\hi) {\item};
        \xdef\fitbox{\fitbox(c\hi)}
    }%
    \node [draw,fit=\fitbox(LegendBox_anchor)] {};
}
\makeatletter

\definecolor{A1}{RGB}{166, 206, 227}
\definecolor{B2}{RGB}{31, 120, 180}
\definecolor{C3}{RGB}{178, 223, 138}
\definecolor{D4}{RGB}{51, 160, 44}
\definecolor{E5}{RGB}{251, 154, 153}
\definecolor{F6}{RGB}{227, 26, 28}
\definecolor{G7}{RGB}{253, 191, 111}
\definecolor{H8}{RGB}{255, 127, 0}
\definecolor{I9}{RGB}{202, 178, 214}
\definecolor{J10}{RGB}{106, 61, 154}
\definecolor{K11}{RGB}{255, 255, 153}
\definecolor{L12}{RGB}{177, 89, 40} 
\definecolor{M13}{RGB}{140, 135, 32}
\definecolor{N14}{RGB}{231, 41, 138}
\definecolor{O15}{RGB}{135, 135, 135}
\definecolor{P16}{RGB}{53, 151, 143}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        
        
        \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={1.5\textwidth},center}
            
            \begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=.15cm]
                \begin{scope}
                    
                    
                    \tkzKiviatDiagram[font= \Large\bf, align=center, line width=1.15 mm, scale=1.25, label distance=.15cm,step=1.25,label space =1.25, gap= 1,lattice=10, lattice space=2]%
                    {People \parbox{1cm}{\centering distribution} ,Color \parbox{2cm}{\centering complexion},Physical \parbox{1cm}{\centering appearance},Nature,Phycology,Height}  
                    %   \draw (0,0)  node [midway] {\textbf{\Large GRMMC}};
                    \kivlattice
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=A1,mark={*},
                    mark size=3.5pt](0.95,3.15,0.95,3.15,3.15,0.95)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=B2,mark={*},
                    mark size=3.5pt](5.55,3.35,5.95,3.35,5.55,3.7) 
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=C3,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](5.75,3.55,6.15,0.95,3.35,3.9)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=D4,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](5.95,3.75,6.35,3.55,5.75,1.15)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=E5,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](6.15,3.95,6.55,1.15,5.95,4.1)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=F6,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](6.35,6.35,6.75,1.35,6.15,1.35)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=G7,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](6.55,6.55,6.95,1.55,6.35,1.55)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=H8,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](3.15,6.75,3.15,6.55,6.55,1.75)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=I9,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](6.75,6.95,1.15,6.75,6.75,1.95)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=J10,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](1.15,4.15,3.35,3.75,6.95,2.15)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=K11,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](6.95,4.35,3.55,6.95,7.15,4.3)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=L12,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](7.15,4.55,7.15,3.95,7.35,2.35)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=M13,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](3.35,0.95,7.35,4.15,3.55,5.7)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=N14,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](7.35,4.75,3.75,1.75,7.55,2.55)
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=O15,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](7.55,7.15,3.95,7.15,7.75,4.5)
                    \LegendBox[shift={(-25cm,-3cm)}]{current bounding box.south east}%
                    {A1/ 1,
                        B2/ 2,
                        C3/ 3 } 
                    \LegendBox[shift={(-20cm,0.4cm)}]{current bounding box.south east}%
                    {D4/ 4,
                        E5/ 5,
                        F6/ 6 }
                    \LegendBox[shift={(-15cm,0.42cm)}]{current bounding box.south east}%
                    {G7/ 7,
                        H8/ 8,%\cite{Guo2020}ZHOU201993
                        I9/ 9 }
                    \LegendBox[shift={(-10cm,0.44cm)}]{current bounding box.south east}%
                    {J10/ 10,
                        K11/ 11,
                        L12/ 12 }
                    \LegendBox[shift={(-5cm,0.46cm)}]{current bounding box.south east}%
                    {M13/ 13,
                        N14/ 14,
                        O15/ 15 }
                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            
        \end{adjustbox}
        \caption{Conclusive findings from the literature after a hasty uncontrolled view  }
        \label{Fig_fig:16New}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: OUTPUT:]

Comment: TikZ draws elements in the order that you provide in the code (mostly). So move `\kivlattice` to _after_ all the `\tkzKiviatLine` statements to draw the labels on top of the lines instead of behind them.

Comment: @Marijn, the plot  markers are crossed by the arrow lines now.

Answer (score 2):

TikZ draws elements in the order that you provide in the code (with some exceptions, notably the `backgrounds` tikzlibrary).

Therefore, if you want the plot markers to be on top of the arrow lines, and the text labels on top of everything, then you should put the code for the arrow lines first, then the code for the plot markers, then the code for the text labels.

The arrow lines and the text labels are drawn together in the `\kivlattice` macro. Therefore, to draw them separately you need to split the macro in two, which requires using the same for-loop twice. Then you can draw the markers with `\tkzKiviatLine` in between the two parts of the lattice.

Code (snippets, not repeating the full MWE from the question):

```
\newcommand{\kivarrowsonly}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisangle}{360/\kivaxisnumbers}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
    {   \foreach \y in {1,...,\kivlcmcatcount}
        {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisstep}{6/\kivlcmcatcount}
            \draw[help lines] (\kivaxisangle*\x:\y*\kivaxisstep) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x+\kivaxisangle:\y*\kivaxisstep);
        }
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
    {  \draw[ultra thick,-|] (0,0) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:1.0cm); 
        \draw[ultra thick,->|] (0,0) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:3.8cm);%-latex,line width=0.55mm
        \draw[ultra thick,->|] (0,0) -- (\kivaxisangle*\x:6.8cm);
     }
}
\newcommand{\kivlattice}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisangle}{360/\kivaxisnumbers}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\kivaxisnumbers}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxissteps}{\kivcategorycounts[\x-1]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\kivaxisstep}{8.5/\kivcategorycounts[\x-1]}
        \foreach \y in {1,...,\kivaxissteps}
        {   %\pgfmathsetmacro{\kivhelper}{\kivkumulativecategorycounts[\x-1]}
            %\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\kivlabelname}{\kivcategorynames[\kivhelper+\y-1]}
            %\node[circle,fill=black,label=\x*\kivaxisangle+90:\kivlabelname,inner sep=1pt] at (\kivaxisangle*\x:\kivaxisstep*\y) {};
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\kivlabelnumber}{\y+1}            
            \node[label=\x*\kivaxisangle+60:\kivcurrentlabel{\x}{\kivlabelnumber}] at (\kivaxisangle*\x:\kivaxisstep*\y) {};
        }
    }
}
%%%%%% [lots of code in between] %%%%%%
\tkzKiviatDiagram[font= \Large\bf, align=center, line width=1.15 mm, scale=1.25, label distance=.15cm,step=1.25,label space =1.25, gap= 1,lattice=10, lattice space=2]%
                    {People \parbox{1cm}{\centering distribution} ,Color \parbox{2cm}{\centering complexion},Physical \parbox{1cm}{\centering appearance},Nature,Phycology,Height}  
                    %   \draw (0,0)  node [midway] {\textbf{\Large GRMMC}};
                    \kivarrowsonly
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=A1,mark={*},
                    mark size=3.5pt](0.95,3.15,0.95,3.15,3.15,0.95)
%%%%%% more \tkzKiviatLine statements here %%%%%%                    
                    \tkzKiviatLine[line width=0.35mm,color=O15,mark={*}, 
                    mark size=3.5pt](7.55,7.15,3.95,7.15,7.75,4.5)
                    \kivlattice
                    \LegendBox[shift={(-25cm,-3cm)}]{current bounding box.south east}%
                    {A1/ 1,
                        B2/ 2,
                        C3/ 3 } 
%%%%%% [...] %%%%%%
```

Result:

[image]